# JQuery .hasClass to change css on child element

Tags: jquery

I want to verify the class of a div by using its ID and checking if it has a specific class. Should the attribute prove to be true, I then want to set the css on a child element inside the DIV being validated. How do I do that?

```
$('#kwick_4').hasClass('active').css('background-position', '0px');
```

The css to be set, should be set on the image child element of the div:

```
#kwick4 img
```

How do I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $elem = $('#kwick_4');

if($elem.hasClass('active')){
    $elem.find('img').css('background-position', '0px');
}
```

OR

Simply

```
 $('#kwick_4.active img').css('background-position', '0px');
```

Comment: @DextrousDave .. Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 4):

`hasClass` returns a boolean value, you can use class selector instead:

```
$('#kwick_4.active').css('background-position', '0px');
```

if you want to style the `img` element you can code:

```
$('#kwick_4.active img').css('property', 'value');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var quick = $('#kwick_4');

if(quick.hasClass('active')){
    quick.find('img').css('background-position', '0px');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( $('#kwick_4').hasClass('active') ) {
   $('#kwick_4 img').css('background-position', '0px');
}
```

Comment: Maybe just insert the class in the selector, as in `#kwick_4.active img`.